# How to query the GAL using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, gal

I am looking for code to query the Global Address List (GAL) to obtain contacts email. I'm able to do this using VBA code. However, I was wondering if it's possible to do the same using SQL code. Also, I thinking about using SSIS package to pull over the data as well.

Comment: You should be able to get to it through an LDAP query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be something similar to:

```
SELECT sAMAccountName, name, mail AS email
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT sAMAccountName, name, mail FROM 
    ''LDAP://myServer/OU=myOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2'' 
    WHERE objectCategory=''person'' AND objectClass = ''user'' '
)
```